# Scala return value from onComplete

Tags: scala

How can I structure onComplete in Scala to act in this way:

Fig. 1

```
{ 
  var x; 
  if(result.isFailure){
    x = foo() // foo is a future
  }

  if(result.isSuccess){
    x = 5
  }  
  bar(x)
}
```

I thought I could do it this way:

Fig. 2

```
var x = foo onComplete {
  case Success(x) => 5
  case Failure(t) => foo() //foo is a future
}
bar(x)
```

But onComplete, onFailure and onSuccess all have `Unit` as their return type,

```
onComplete[U](f: (Try[T]) ⇒ U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
onSuccess[U](pf: PartialFunction[T, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
onFailure[U](pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, U])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

How can I achieve something figure two-ish without using a var?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is discouraged to block current thread by awaiting a result from a future. Instead, you should call bar() function on processing results of the `result` future.

```
result map {r =>
   5
} recover {
   case _ => foo()
} map {r => 
   bar(r)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't recover only catches Exceptions? Could a Failure be there without an Exception? Just asking out of curiosity here.

Comment: Future can be failed only with an exception. Either it can be thrown and not catched inside a future's body, or, for instance, a promise that created thad future was completed with `failure` method, which parameterized with Throwable.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @alexander

Comment: sometimes you want, the recover to only recover from the inital result and NOT be fed into bar ... hmmm

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve your goal with

```scala
val x: Future[Int] = foo.map(x => 5).recover{case f => foo()}
// do some more work with your future
x.map(bar(_))
```

Assuming that `foo: Future[_]` and `foo(): Int`.

Comment: can you think of how to do it without an `Await` to not block?

Comment: @krzasteka, I only used `Await` here to visualise that at some point of your computation when you want to retrieve the result of your `Future` that you have to wait for it. But it's right that you can chain further operations to the future `x`.